# What are the negative & sample parameters?

Tags: doc2vec

I am new to NLP and doc2Vec. I want to understand the parameters of doc2Vec. Thank you

```
Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=300, negative=5, hs=0, sample = 0, seed=0)
```

1. vector_size:I believe this is to control over-fitting. A larger feature vector will learn more details so it tends to over-fit. Is there a method to determine a appropriate vector size based on the number of document or total words in all doc?
2. negative: how many “noise words” should be drawn. What is noise word?
3. sample: the threshold for configuring which higher-frequency words are randomly down sampled. So what does sample=0 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner, only `vector_size` will be of initial interest.

Typical values are 100-1000, but larger dimensionalities require far more training data & more memory. There's no hard & fast rules – try different values, & see what works for your purposes.

Very vaguely, you'll want your count of unique vocabulary words to be much larger than the `vector_size`, at least the square of the `vector_size`: the gist of the algorithm is to force many words into a smaller-number of dimensions. (If for some reason you're running experiments on tiny amounts of data with a tiny vocabulary – for which word2vec isn't really good anyway – you'll have to shrink the `vector_size` very low.)

The `negative` value controls a detail of how the internal neural network is adjusted: how many random 'noise' words the network is tuned *away from predicting* for each target positive word it's tuned *towards predicting*. The default of 5 is good unless/until you have a repeatable way to rigorously score other values against it.

Similarly, `sample` controls how much (if at all) more-frquent words are sometimes randomly skipped (down-sampled). (So many redundant usage examples are overkill, wasting training time/effort that could better be spent on rarer words.) Again, you'd only want to tinker with this if you've got a way to compare the results of alternate values. Smaller values make the downsampling more aggressive (dropping more words). `sample=0` would turn off such down-sampling completely, leaving all training text words used.

Though you didn't ask:

`dm=0` turns off the default PV-DM mode in favor of the PV-DBOW mode. That will train doc-vectors a bit faster, and often works very well on short texts, but *won't* train word-vectors at all (unless you turn on an extra `dbow_words=1` mode to add-back interleaved ski-gram word-vector training).

`hs` is an alternate mode to train the neural-network that uses multi-node encodings of words, rather than one node per (positive or negative) word. If enabled via `hs=1`, you should disable the negative-sampling with `negative=0`. But negative-sampling mode is the default for a reason, & tends to get relatively better with larger amounts of training data - so it's rare to use this mode.